# Activate Night Light option from terminal

Tags: configuration, gnome3, display-settings

Recently Gnome came up with a new feature of Night Light. It is really helpful.
It feels too time-consuming that I need to go to settings (and then display) and activate it each time. **Is there any terminal command that can simply turn on the night light feature?**
Manual and/or sunrise to sunset option aren't really helpful as even I don't know when I will be needing that particular feature to turn on or off.
I tried to google but, found nothing related to command.
Might not matter, but just in case, I am using Kali Linux.
This is the feature I am talking about.
[image]

Comment: You mean gnome, right? This is a gnome feature, not a kernel feature.

Comment: Yes! That's right.

Comment: @Zip if this is Gnome feature then why I didnt found it in Ubuntu ?

Comment: @InfiniteLoops Which version fo Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Another way (cron+redshift) described here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/991832/redshift-configuration-how-to-set-fixed-transition-hours

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can turn it on with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled true
```

or

```
dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/color/night-light-enabled true
```

Same commands with `false` instead of `true` will turn it off.

---

If you list the keys under the `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color` schema you'll see that you can also configure the schedule (auto: on/off, manual: from/to) as well as the night light temperature. A very convenient way to set the latter is via the [*night light slider extension*](https://github.com/TimurKiyivinski/gnome-shell-night-light-slider-extension).

Comment: The first command is now giving the error:
*GLib-GIO-Message: Using the 'memory' GSettings backend.  Your settings will not be saved or shared with other applications.*
The second one is working fine. **What could be the reason?**

Comment: @Ugnes - google for that error and you'll see there are plenty of possible causes. FWIW I can't reproduce it... works fine here.

Comment: @don_crissti I am able to execute the commands that you mentioned as follows: 
`$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled true;
$ gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.color night-light-enabled;
true`. But nothing happens. I opened dconf-editor GUI, and the value doesn't change there, even though using `gsettings get` outputs changed value. What should be done?